# How to detect links in programmatically created TextView

Tags: android, textview

I've programmatically created **TextView** and then set data in it. But I'm not able to detect the links inside the data.

This is the code:

```
TextView dataView = new TextView(this);
dataView.setLayoutParams(dataParams);
dataView.setText("www.google.com");
```

I've tried with the : `dataView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`
and

```
dataView.setLinksClickable(true);
```

but it doesn't works for me.

It will be great if anyone can help me here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    Linkify.addLinks(dataView, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    dataView.setLinksClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
dataView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView tv = (TextView)v;
    String link = tv.getText().toString();
  }

};);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView dataView = new TextView(this);
       dataView.setLayoutParams(dataParams);
       dataView.setText( Html.fromHtml("<b><a style='text-color:white;' href='"+"http://www.google.com"+"'>Google</a></b>"));
       dataView. setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```